# INSERTing rows that is not in a table

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm using this query but it is really really slow

```
   INSERT INTO a (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) SELECT b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i FROM z WHERE b NOT IN (SELECT b FROM a)
```

What is does is find all records where b is not in table "a" from table z and importing it into table a.

Its really really slow and keeps timing. Is there away to make it quicker?

Thank-you
BigThings

P.s.

Comment: Have you checked if the select part is slow (eg by running it and/or by studying the output of explain select ...)?  Just asking because especially on heavily indexed tables inserts can be relatively slow, which is why before bulk inserts it's a good idea to drop the indexes.

Comment: Do you have an index on `b`? (in both tables)

Comment: Are they InnoDB or MyISAM tables?

Comment: How many rows would this insert? What types are the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `b` column unique, then `INSERT` with the [`IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) option, so:

```
   INSERT IGNORE INTO a (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
     SELECT b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i FROM z
```

Comment: And what if `b` cannot be made `UNIQUE` ?

Comment: Then at least create an index on ``a.b`` and ``z.b`` to speed up the comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO a (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) SELECT a.b,a.c,a.d,a.e,a.f,a.g,a.h,a.i FROM z,a WHERE z.b != a.b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   INSERT INTO a (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) SELECT b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i FROM z WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM a WHERE z.b = a.b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple trick:

```
INSERT INTO a (b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i) 
SELECT b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i 
FROM z
LEFT JOIN a on a.b = z.b
WHERE a.b IS NULL;
```

You'll only get a row when there isn't a matching row in `b`, and the query will be able to use indexes effectively.

Comment: I don't think there is much difference in performance (if any) between `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL`. The problem probably lies elsewhere (not indexed tables, big size fields, ...)